# Set different font for page number in table of contents MS WORD

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I have my document in Times New Roman including the header styles but the page numbers in the footer are in different font, Nepali to be precise. When I create an automatic table of contents (TOC), the contents are in Times new roman but the page numbers are not in Nepali (It's also in Times new roman). I want the page numbers only to show in the same font as used in the footer. Is there any way to do this automatically without having to manually select the page numbers and change its font every time I update my TOC?

Comment: Does [this article](https://word.tips.net/T007693_Two_Types_of_Page_Numbers_in_a_TOC.html) help with the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, NO! The article talks about changing footer page numbers from inbuilt numerals, arabic, alphabetic types and showing it on TOC. Rather, I want to change the footer page number font to a different language and show it in TOC as well.

Answer (score -1):

The answer can be found at this Microsoft support page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-or-customize-a-table-of-contents-9d85eb9c-0b55-4795-8abb-a49885b3a58d

Comment: Welcome to SU! Without even opening the link I know it's the right answer :-) However it's not really what's considered a _good_ one. The problem with it is that this link may be dead tomorrow, which makes your answer null and void; not really a good thing in a Q&A site. Have a look at [how to write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and update yours accordingly, leave the link as a source reference and you're golden :-) As it now is, this will get deleted.